# How can I mount NFS file in unix?

Tags: unix, mount, shell-script, nfs

I am using Cent OS 5.6 and I have two VMs. I am trying to mount a file but unable to do so. 
Here's what I have done.

```
Mkdir/uxadm
Chmod 777 /uxadm



vi /etc/exports
         /uxadm w01(no_root_squash,rw,sync,no_acl)

Service nfs restart
```

(on another vm)

```
mkdir /uxadm
vi /etc/fstab 
          10.5.2.20:/uxadm      /uxadm      nfs rw,soft,timeo=5 0 0
```

It gives me error saying that "permission denied from server".

What is that I need to change here?

Comment: Have you confirmed nfs is actually running on the host?  What errors do you see in `/varlog/messages` or `/var/log/secure`

Comment: I have two vms, (as I mentioned earlier) one acts as a server and another as a workstation. So, by host you mean server, right??

Comment: Yep the nfs server.

Comment: There are multiple messages in /var/log/secure. First was session is closed for user root, followed by session opened for user root(uid=0), and then again closed session.

Then received signal terminating, server listening to port 22 and at last, session opened for user root by(uid=0)

Comment: Please can you post the result of running `exportfs` e.g. what's actually mounted?

Comment: That's the point, nothing is being mounted. It says permission denied. I changed the permission then also it says permission denied.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check firewall rules
2. Check whether NFS server exports any directory

   ```
   showmount -e
   ```
3. Remove no_acl option from /etc/exports file. This option is specifically used any NFS version 3 shares.
4. After editing /etc/exports file, run the following command

   ```
   exportfs -av
   ```
5. Check NFS shares on NFS client
6. NFS server and NFS client should have identical uid and gid for a particular user or group. See my answer for an idea [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/172514/mounting-a-nfs-file-system-by-changing-default-owner/172671#172671). If this is not the case, use ldap server to configure user accounts and on NFS client machine, configure ldap client for user authentication and autofs service for automounting NFS shares.

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26187345/iptables-rules-for-nfs-server-and-nfs-client/27393897#27393897) which may be helpful.